# How to Reverse-GeoCode an array of Lat/Longs

Tags: c#, dictionary, reverse-geocoding

I am looking for the ability in C# .Net to find the address from an array of Latitudes and Longitudes. My array would have something like the following (39.96481959995778, -83.00803899765015),(39.96575701532093, -83.00681591033936). From the coordinates i would get back all the address within that area. i appreciate any help with this.

Comment: That's called reverse geo-coding.  You need to find a web service that will do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called as **Reverse-GeoCoding**. You need to use a third party webservice (free or paid) that returns the user addresses on the basis of Lat/Long. Google has one like this See this on how to use google for this purpose.[GEO CODING](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services#Geocoding_Direct) but there are other such services as well. You find one that is right for you. If you are using it in a commercial environment i guess you will have to purchase a license for that.